# Filtering DataFrame with Multiple Criteria - Skipping Blank Criteria

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe and 4 variables that will be used to filter the dataframe, which are supplied by the user (country, company_type, etc.). The following formula works for when all the 4 variables are set.

```
search_table = master_df.loc[(master_df['country'].isin(country)) 
                                    & (master_df['company_type'].isin(company_type))
                                    & (master_df['sector'].isin(sector))
                                    & (master_df['state'].isin(state))
                                    ]
```

However, sometimes the user will not select all 4 variables and the code will not work. How can I write the code in such a way that it will ignore the variables that are `None` without having to write multiple `If` statements?

Comment: How does the user declare these lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the variables exist then you could organize them in a dict and do the following:

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import and_

variables = {'country': country, 'company_type': company_type,
             'sector': sector, 'state': state}

selection = reduce(and_, [master_df[v_str].isin(v)
                          for v_str, v in variables.items()
                          if v is not None])
search_table = master_df.loc[selection]
```

[and_](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/operator.html?highlight=and_#operator.and_) is the function version of `&` (`and_(a, b)` is the same as `a & b`). And [reduce](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functools.html?highlight=reduce#functools.reduce) aggregates the conditions in the list successively by `and_`.

But: At least one variable has to be different from `None`. If that's not guaranteed you could do:

```
selection = []
if any(variables.values()):
    selection = reduce(and_, [master_df[v_str].isin(v)
                              for v_str, v in variables.items()
                              if v is not None])
search_table = master_df.loc[selection]
```

If it's not clear that the variables exist then something like this could work:

```
variables = {'country', 'company_type', 'sector', 'state'}

selection = reduce(and_, [master_df[v].isin(globals()[v])
                          for v in variables
                          if globals().get(v, None) is not None])
search_table = master_df.loc[selection]
```

Comment: I'm getting an empty dataframe when I use the second case (all variables can be none).

Comment: got it to work now. I just changed from `if v is not None` to just `if v`. Not exactly sure what the difference between the two is but thanks a bunch!!!

Comment: @pandashugger The difference is: The version in the answer blocks variables that are _strictly_ `None`, whereas your version blocks variables with a truth-value of `False`, and that includes empty lists. So my guess would be that one of the variables was an `[]`?

Comment: yes I had an empty list - thanks very much for the clarification

Answer (score 0):

```
search_table = master_df.loc[(master_df['country'].isin(country)) 
                                    & (master_df['company_type'].isin(company_type) if company_type else True)
                                    & (master_df['sector'].isin(sector) if sector else True)
                                    & (master_df['state'].isin(state) if state else True)
                                    ]
```

Comment: I think this will crash due to the evaluation order of `... if ... else ...`  statements (from left to right).